# How to recognize Conda using Reticulate for installing SpacyR

Tags: r, spacy, quanteda

I'm trying to install spacyr on a Windows 10 machine with R 3.6.1. and Visual Studio Community 2019.

When trying to spacy_install() I get this error:

"Error: Conda installation failed (no conda binary found)

Install Anaconda 3.x for Windows (https://www.anaconda.com/download/#windows)
before installing spaCy"

I had already installed Miniconda3 4.7.12 and after failing I installed Anaconda3 2019.10 (Python 3.7.4 64-bit).

Looking at the code in https://github.com/quanteda/spacyr/blob/master/R/spacy_install.R I tried reticulate::py_versions_windows() and I get:

```
    type hive               install_path                        executable_path version arch
```

1 PythonCore  HCU C:\Users\user\ANACON~1 C:\Users\camil\ANACON~1\python.exe     3.7  x64
2   Anaconda  HCU C:\Users\user\ANACON~1 C:\Users\camil\ANACON~1\python.exe     3.7  x64

But when I try reticulate::conda_binary("auto") I get:
Error: Unable to find conda binary. Is Anaconda installed?

I also tried installing spacy in Python through pip and conda (not both at the same time) and that doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm having the same issue (3+ yrs later) - did you ever find a solution? If so would you mind sharing it here as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  I fixed it by doing the following (adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60974507/error-unable-to-find-conda-binary-is-anaconda-installed))

Find the path to your miniconda `bin` by looking in the path from here:
`path.expand(reticulate::py_versions_windows()$install_path)`

Then:

`original_path <- Sys.getenv("PATH")`

`Sys.setenv("PATH" = paste("path\\to\\anaconda\\bin", original_path, sep = ";"))`

Notice `"PATH"` is in quotes, double slashes `\\` and `sep = ;` - these are what worked for me, but are different than given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60974507/error-unable-to-find-conda-binary-is-anaconda-installed)

Then proceed as per `spacyr` instructions:

`library(spacyr)`

`spacy_install()`