# Error: Unable to find conda binary. Is Anaconda installed?

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I am trying to run python scripts in R. I have a macOS Catalina 10.15.4 and I continue to receive this error:

```
"Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Need to install Anaconda from https://www.anaconda.com/download/.
Error: Unable to find conda binary. Is Anaconda installed?"
```

I have already downloaded python 3.8 and I have already downloaded anaconda. After exhausting Google searches. I'm learning that the path for my conda might be the issue. Google searches then recommend using "use_condaenv()" to specify the correct path, but I still receive the same error: Error: Unable to find conda binary. Is Anaconda installed?"

In short: **How do I find the correct location of my binary conda? How do I correct the path accurately? How to I resolve the error?**

Here is the syntax I've ran so far:

```
install.packages("reticulate")

library(reticulate)

repl_python()

Python 2.7.16 (/usr/bin/python)

Reticulate 1.13 REPL -- A Python interpreter in R.

reticulate::py_config()

python:         /usr/bin/python
libpython:      /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.dylib
pythonhome:     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
version:        2.7.16 (default, Feb 29 2020, 01:55:37)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.29.20) (-macos10.15-objc-
numpy:          /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy
numpy_version:  1.8.0

python versions found: 
 /usr/bin/python
 /usr/bin/python3
 /usr/local/bin/python3

use_python("/usr/bin/python3", required = TRUE)

**ERROR: The requested version of Python ('/usr/bin/python3') cannot be used, as another version of
Python ('/usr/bin/python') has already been initialized. Please restart the R session if you need
to attach reticulate to a different version of Python.
Error in use_python("/usr/bin/python3", required = TRUE) : 
  failed to initialize requested version of Python**

Sys.which("python")

           python 
"/usr/bin/python" 

install.packages("youtubecaption")

library(youtubecaption)

**The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/n2/kl03cmjj04n5msjq8x8mt_yr0000gn/T//RtmpD82WW0/downloaded_packages**

url<-"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qATvD6kQ47s&t=339s" #this is just an example url#

caption<-get_caption(url)

**Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Need to install Anaconda from https://www.anaconda.com/download/.
Error: Unable to find conda binary. Is Anaconda installed?**
```

Comment: What version of conda did you install? Python 2 or python 3? Based on the code above, you're trying to mix python 2 and 3, which definitely won't work.

Comment: I installed python 3.8. I tried to specify that by putting: use_python("/usr/bin/python3", required = TRUE) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three different things you can try.

## `RETICULATE_PYTHON` environment variable

Reticulate also searches for an environment variable `RETICULATE_PYTHON`, where you can define the python you want to use. Define [here](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/blob/1ee334ba92fd73a943fba2b3f33762383742bbef/R/config.R#L108).

```
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "path/to/anaconda/bin/python")
library(reticulate)
# and so on
```

---

## `reticulate.conda_binary` option

`reticulate` has an option to specify the conda executable (define [here](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/blob/1ee334ba92fd73a943fba2b3f33762383742bbef/R/conda.R#L326)). Can you try this?

```r
options(reticulate.conda_binary = "path/to/bin/conda")
library(reticulate)
```

---

## `PATH` environment variable

You can also try setting your `PATH` variable within R to include your `anaconda/bin` directory:

```
# Prepend the anaconda/bin directory so that python installation 
# is found before any others.
original_path <- Sys.getenv("PATH")
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("path/to/anaconda/bin", original_path, sep = ":"))

library(reticulate)
reticulate::py_config()
# and so on
```

Comment: For new macs based on apple silicon (M1), conda is installed by miniforge instead of miniconda, so the conda path looks different, usually like this: `~/miniforge3/condabin/conda`